# Mouse not working after boot: dmesg: couldn't allocate usb_device

Tags: boot, usb, kernel, mouse

I ran into this problem on different PCs. All that happens after kernel-upgrade
I am currently on a Acer-Laptop with "Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS" and Kernel "5.4.0-100-generic" and two connected mice's.
The mice's are not working after boot (LED off), but if I un- and replug their USB-Plug they are working normally.
DMESG: Shows "couldn't allocate usb_device" for the ports the mice's are connected.
I found some bug reports on RedHat, but I am unsure if this has something to do with my problem.
I had similar problems on another PC (can't acess it right now).
So what should I do.. What additional information is needed ?